# Instagram graph api, my app doesnt show the same data as Graph API Explorer (laravel)

Tags: instagram-graph-api

`im trying to get data from my Instagram business account (followers_count,media_count)

i have this request`

$response = Http::get("https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{$BAccountId}?fields=business_discovery.username({$userName}){followers_count,media_count}&access_token={$access_token}");

`my token has this permission`         $permission = [
'public_profile',
'instagram_basic',
'pages_show_list',
'business_management',
'pages_read_engagement',
'pages_manage_metadata',
'pages_read_user_content',
'ads_management',
'instagram_manage_insights',
'leads_retrieval',
];

`i get this data`  
{
"business_discovery" : {
"id": "my account id"
}
"id": "my account id"
{

`but when i use Graph API Explorer to send the same request with the same token and data i get the  full response` 
{
"business_discovery": {
"followers_count": 0,
"media_count": 1,
"id": "my account id"
},
"id": "my account id"
}
`am i missing permission or something ?`  
`my response missing some data`